# PHP - Find file in Directory based on date /YEAR/MONTH/DAY - But not based on current date - static Datestamp

Tags: php, date, datetime, directory, subdirectory

I have a variable pulled from a SQL DB which is in the "datetime" format of:

```
2017-02-22 16:24:12
```

I will be needing to find a file in this directory based on the results of the remaining code, but im not sure how to format the date variables for the directory.

Eg:

```
/basefolder/2017/02/22/File.extension
```

I have read lots about using date variables, but they are all based on the current date. My thoughts were that I could just strip the numbers like

```
/basefolder/"first 4 numbers"/"second 2 numbers"/"last 2 numbers"/
```

VS trying to do this with any sort of date/time functions. But perhaps there is a date fuction I can/should use.

I do know that the datetime will always be formatted as such, but it feels "hackish" to do it the first way. I could do it in bash in a second, but I'm not so good w/ PHP.

Thanks for any help!

PS: To give context, I will be getting 2 variables passed to this php script, phone number and date. I will then query the CDR table for the Unique ID of this call record based on that information, then I know the file will be in:

```
/monitor/2017/02/22/*uniqueID*
```

Which I will then pass back to the original script to have it download the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `strtotime` to convert your date string to a timestamp, and then use the `date` function to create the date formatted as you like, and you can pass the timestamp as the second argument (it only uses current time if you pass only the format)

docs for `strtotime`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
<?php
$dateString = '2017-02-22 16:24:12';

$timestamp = strtotime($dateString);

$datepath = date('Y/m/d',$timestamp);

$path = "/basefolder/$datepath/";

var_dump($path);
```

This outputs: `string(20) "/basefolder/2017/02/22/"`

This code could be shortened to:

```
$path = "/basefolder/".date('Y/m/d/',strtotime('2017-02-22 16:24:12'));
```

It sounds like you already found the date function but there is more info on it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Note that you have to do it in two stages, as if you include the `/basefolder/` part in the format passed to date, then it will replace individual characters with various formats of the date - e.g.:

```
$datepath = date('/basefolder/Y/m/d',$timestamp);
```

Sets `$datepath` to something like `bpm12US/Pacificf2017Wednesday22US/PacificWed, 22 Feb 2017 16:24:12 -0800/2017/02/22`

`b` is left alone because it means nothing, but then `a` is replaced with `pm` because of the time, `s` is replaced with the seconds value, `e` is replaced with the time zone and so on.

Comment: +1 for more detail, but @spinkus used less code, and also, what I have read about strtotime so far has only been that its "hit and miss", Thank for another method tho!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers `strtotime` is fine for certain formats, I have never heard of an issue converting from MySqls DATETIME function - also my code could be shorter I expanded it to make it clearer. Readable code is always better than aiming for the shortest possible implementation in the long run

Comment: Yes, I completley understand your reasoning for making the answer as such, and love the shortened one-liner, I made the "one-liner" all variables, which is the way I love my code see my answer!

Answer (score 1):

[date_parse_from_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) will convert from string to broken down time array:

```
<?php
$d = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2017-02-22 16:24:12");
$ds = sprintf("/base/%d/%02d/%d", $d['year'], $d['month'], $d['day']);
echo $ds;
```

Comment: This looks great, printing the base path worked, but how can I turn that into a variable $path like @Theo answer? - This is probably something I can figure out on my own, I'm new to PhP

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers sprintf is like printf but returns instead of printing so `$path=sprintf("base/%d/%02d/%d", $d['year'], $d['month'], $d['day']);`

Comment: I will keep this around, as I said, strtotime doesn't always work from what I read, but in this case, the date will always be formatted as such, but I understand now that I could change '"Y-m-d H:i:s"' to fit the format of the time string

Comment: Oh yep, sprintf(). On formats it's generally best to specify exactly what you want if you can and Fail fast if something goes wrong. But strftime() has it uses too.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code snippit!

```
<?php

$dateString = '2017-02-22 16:24:12';
$base = "/monitor/";

$path = "$base".date('Y/m/d/',strtotime("$dateString"));

echo $path;

?>
```